# Perl thread interrupt sleep not work

Tags: multithreading, perl, sleep

I want to understand because if I run this piece of code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub mythread {
    my $end = 0; # Thread termination variable

    while(!$end) {
        eval {
            local $SIG{'ALRM'} = sub {
                print "SIGALARM received\n";
                $end = 1;
                die "Alarm!\n";
            };

            sleep(5); # Wait
        };
        die $@ unless $@ eq "Alarm!\n";
    }
}

my $end = 0; # Main termination variable
$SIG{'INT'} = sub {
    $end = 1; # Set Main termination variable
};

my $thr = threads->create( \&mythread );
while(!$end) {
    sleep(1);
    print "1 second passed\n";
}

print "Send SIGALARM to thread\n";
$thr->kill( "SIGALRM" );

print "Main Wait for thread end\n";
$thr->join();
```

if I hit CTRL-C, main thread catch the signal correctly, but when send the signal to mythread sleep not terminate, but wait 5 second even I wrap the code in a eval like [Perldoc sleep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Signals can only be sent to processes, not threads. From `$thread->kill`'s documentation:

> CAVEAT: The thread signalling capability provided by this module does not actually send signals via the OS. It emulates signals at the Perl-level such that signal handlers are called in the appropriate thread. For example, sending `$thr->kill('STOP')` does not actually suspend a thread (or the whole process), but does cause a `$SIG{'STOP'}` handler to be called in that thread (as illustrated above).

The OS doesn't know anything about your request, so your `sleep` doesn't get interrupted.

---

In this case, you could use something like the following:

```
use Time::HiRes qw( );

sub polling_sleep {
    my ($dur) = @_;
    my $until = Time::HiRes::time() + $dur;
    while (1) {
       $dur = $until - Time::HiRes::time();
       last if $dur < 0;
       Time::HiRes::sleep($dur < 0.5 ? $dur : 0.5);
    }
}

polling_sleep(5);
```

There's no general solution.